# Getting 400 responce for dropwizard API from Andorid Volley

Tags: java, android, api, android-volley, dropwizard

I'm New to Dropwizard. I have created Resource for API Request. API is working with Postman with the same payload but not working with an android volley.

UserDTO.java

```
public class UserDTO {

private String emailId;
private String fcmToken;
private String password;

public String getEmailId() {
return emailId;
}

public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
this.emailId = emailId;
}

public String getFcmToken() {
return fcmToken;
}

public void setFcmToken(String fcmToken) {
this.fcmToken = fcmToken;
}

public String getPassword() {
return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
this.password = password;
}

}
```

UserResource.java

```
    @Path(URLConstants.USER)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public class UserResource {

      @POST
      @UnitOfWork
      @Path(URLConstants.CREATE)
      public Response createUser(UserDTO userDTO) throws Exception {

      // I want UserDTO Object here.

      }
    }
```

I'm trying to hit user/create API, It works with POSTMAN but I'm getting 400 when I hit API from an android volley.

Comment: What is the JSON that is being sent across? Are you also sending the "Content-Type" header in the request?